# CvBOX2D Processing

Tags: image, opencv

I've already got my ROI(CvBOX2D type) by series of contour processing, now I just want to focus on the image part within the ROI, e.g.: feed this part into another processing function, how can I do that? I know there is CvSetImageROI, but the type is CvRect, so I should convert CvBox2D to CvRect first? Or some way to apply a mask on it with the area outside the box set to 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the angle of the CvBox2D object?  If it is parallel to either the x or y axis, converting it to a CvRect should be trivial (look at CvBox2D.size)

Comment: It varies a lot due to the image, it may or may not parallel to either x or y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Only axis aligned ROIs are directly supported in OpenCV (CvRect or IplROI). This is because they allow direct access to the image memory buffer.

There are 2 ways to go about working on a *non*-axis aligned ROI in OpenCV. Neither of them is as efficient as using axis-aligned ROIs.

1. Rotate your image, or bounding box, so that your ROI is now axis aligned in the resulting rotated image.
   **Note:** the rotation will slightly blur your image.
2. Use a mask: Draw your ROI as a white rectangle on a black BG the same size as the image, and give your processing functions this mask as the additional parameter.
   **Note:** not all functions support masks.

I would recommend option 1 if you really must stay within the exact bounds of your ROI. Otherwise, just use the bounding rect.

Answer (score 0):

Use c++ api of opencv. seriously. do it.

```
cv::Rect roi = cv::RotatedRect(box).boundingRect();
Mat_<type> working_area(original_mat, roi);
// now operate on working_area
```

Note: this will operate on the bounding rect. I didn't find information on how to create a mask out of rotatedrect. Probably you have to do it by hand in a scanline fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry not quite familiar with C++, I am using objective-c instead, can I still use the api u provided above?

Comment: AFAIK unfortunately there exist no ObjectiveC bindings for the new API. :(